# How to use MyBatis/Spring from main()

Tags: spring, program-entry-point, mybatis

So I've been working on a web application using MyBatis and Spring. I realized that I will need a nightly batch process. I'd like to be able to reuse my MyBatis code and use Spring so I can autowire things, but the autowiring doesn't seem to be working. Basically, I want to be able to do this:

```
public class mainMethod{
    @Autowired
    Mapper m; 

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       System.out.println(m.selectByPrimaryKey("key"); 
    }
}
```

Obviously, this is an overly simplified example, but once that works, I'll be able to do everything else I need to. Right now, m is null, and I'm not sure how to make it autowire properly.

Comment: You need to create an ApplicationContext somehow. In your `main()` method do something like `ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/app-context.xml");` and then `Mapper mapper = (Mapper) ctx.getBean("myMapper");`. These are the obvious things, unless your code sample is so overly simplified that you completely missed the creation of an `ApplicationContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use only spring you cannot inject dependencies to main class directly and should explicitly create context and get beans from it:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("path/to/app/context.xml");
    ctx.getBean(Mapper.class);
}
```

The reason for this is that spring can only inject dependencies to beans it creates and controls. Think of this another way: spring needs to get control to inject dependencies. In the above example spring gets control when application context is created. You can of cause inject dependencies manually but this seems not what you want.

There is another option: you can use [spring boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/). In this case main can look like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class YouCommandLineApp implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private Mapper mapper;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
       System.out.println(m.selectByPrimaryKey("key"); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       SpringApplication.run(YouCommandLineApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at https://code.google.com/p/standalone-spring-application/, it might be helpful for you

The important class to look at is this

At Main.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ((Main) new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(CONTEXT).getBean("main")).job();

}
```